# Сравнить значение массива на PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте. Есть массив

```
[cart] => Array
    (
        [32] => 31
        [29] => 31
        [30] => 31
        [22] => 5
        [20] => 5
    )
```

как в этом массиве сравнить значение, и если они равны то добавить их ключи к одну строку. 
Например так: значение ключа 32 совпадает со значению 29 и 30, нужно взять эти ключи (32,29,30) и добавить в строку srt_30 = (32,29,30).
Можно вообще такое осуществить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

создаем пустой массив

```
$out = array();
```

заполняем его наоборот, ключи становятся значениями, а значения ключами

```
foreach($cart as $key => $value){
    $out[$value][] = $key;
}
```

обходим получившийся массив, и если в нем больше 1 значения, создаем строку

```
foreach($out as $key => $value){
   if(count($value) > 1) echo "srt_" . $key ." = (" . implode(",", $value) . ")";
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо всем, получилось.

Comment: За "спасибо" спасибо, ответ примите :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$out = array();
foreach($cart as $key => $value){
    $out["str_".$value][] = $key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = [1 => 42, 2 => 2.2, 3 => 42, 4 => 5, 6 => 42];
$val = 42;

function fn($arr, $n){
  return implode(',', array_reduce(array_keys($arr), function($acc, $e) use ($arr, $n){
    if($arr[$e] === $n)
      $acc[] = $e;

    return $acc;
  }, []));
}

var_dump(fn($arr, $val)); // string(5) "1,3,6"
```

https://repl.it/EfHT/0